# Custom button which will change text color, background color and drawable on click

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have a `Button` XML file in `/drawable/` which changes states of the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_normal"
          android:state_focused="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_normal"/>
</selector>
```

And this Ok if I will change background only on click event.

But now, I have a button with left drawable, and on click I have to change left drawable, text color and button background.

```
Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="My button"
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_leftDrawable"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Can I do this inside this XML and how? I don't want to make spaghetti code by doing these extra tasks inside Java code in `setOnClickListener` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create three different xml selector and add them to the corresponding attributes..

Sample:

**TextColor:**

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="@color/click"/>

<item android:color="@color/normal"/>
```

**Background:**

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="@color/buttonBackgroundClick"/>

<item android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

**Add them to your button:**

```
Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="My button"
   android:textColor="@drawable/textColor"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_leftDrawable"
   android:background="@drawable/background"
/>
```

Comment: Right, has to make one XML for each task. Thanks